# Debian 11 PHP db2_connect() not working / PECL installed ibm_db2

Tags: php, db2, debian, pecl

I have taken the following steps and I am using Debian 11.

- I've installed the CLI Driver for DB/2 from the IBM Website
- I've installed the ibm_db2 package via pecl for PHP [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2)
- I've edited the PHP.INI Files for both apache2 and CLI.
- My PHP script is executing and it acceptes the db2_connect() command

Nevertheless, it's not connecting to my DB/2 server. I've ensured that I have connectivity from the Debian Server to the DB/2 Server.

I am getting constantly the following message:

> PHP Warning:  db2_connect(): SQLGetDiagRec returned -2 (is the driver working?) in /var/www/html/db2.php on line 7
> Connection failed.Done Processing

Any help is appreciated.
Is the $database string correct? Are there any other setup setps to be taken?

This is my PHP script so far:

```
<?php
$database = 'NAMZPR1:50055';
$user = 'bouser';
$password = 'xxx';

$conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password);

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo "Connection failed.";
}

echo "Done Processing ...";
?>
```

Comment: Did you set the required environment variables correctly ( example LD_LIBRARY_PATH, IBM_DB_HOME, PATH ) for the userid/account that runs PHP (i.e the account that runs apache)?  You get this symptom when the db2cli driver cannot load or cannot initialize itself due to configuration problems.  See https://github.com/php/pecl-database-ibm_db2

Comment: I still have "connection failed". Adding the environment variables helped. What to put in the $database variable ? IP-address?

Comment: The database field can either be a DSN ( you put DSN details into your db2dsdriver.cfg file externally),  or instead a  connection string ( all details are inside your php script). Refer to docs. Example: `$connection_string="DATABASE=xxx;HOSTNAME=yyy;PORT=60000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=zzz;PWD=www" ;` See IBM php scripts , which are in `~/sqllib/samples/php` (for Db2-instance owner on the Db2-server),  also online in the knowledge centre:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=api-php-samples , also in github https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/tree/master/php

Comment: @mao: I've rebooted my Debian server and the problem re-occured. I am puzzled. I've added the following lines:

export IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/lib64
export LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/lib64
export PATH=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/bin:$PATH

What to do next?

Comment: I got again Connection failed. [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "3". SQLCODE=-1024 ???

Comment: The change you made is unclear. The change needs to be made permanent by editing the *correct* startup file, owned by the correct userid, and you additionally must ensure that the file-and-directory permissions for *that* userid must include rwx for the clidriver directories (typically done by ensuring that clidriver gets unzipped into the home directory of the account that runs apache), and that that same account startup files are correctly edited to make env vars persistent. Vrify each of these things to find your error.

Comment: now its working again on PHP CLI but not in apache/ via browser...

Answer (score 0):

It has turned out that either the db2dsdriver.cfg has to be edited or a valid connection string in PHP has to be used. Here is a sample PHP.

```
<?php
$connection_string="DATABASE= ;HOSTNAME= ;PORT= ;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID= ;PWD= ";

$conn = db2_connect($connection_string, "", "");

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo "Connection failed. " . db2_conn_errormsg() . " ???";
}
 
?>
```

Also, ensure that the environment variables have been set. Thanks and acknowledgement to "mao".